# How to set the title of a menu in Android

Tags: java, android, menu, title

I'm trying to dynamically set the title of my menu.

Retrieving and setting it as such:

```
ItemView menuTitle = ((ItemView) findViewById(R.id.menu_filter));
menuTitle.setTitle("TITLE_HERE");
```

works just fine so long as it's in the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method.

I haven't been able to find a way to set this from the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` or `onCreateOptionsMenu` methods as `findViewById` returns null (even after inflating the menu).

Oddly enough there doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation for accomplishing this and google searches haven't turned up much for such a seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 5):

I must have just derped and not realized that there is a function for Menu called findItem...

```
menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_TITLE).setTitle("MY TITLE");
```

Answer (score 3):

To dynamically set menu title, you'd do this in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, MyActivity.MENU_ID, 0, "Your Title").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return (true);
}
```

and as conditions change (i.e. as your title needs to change), call

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

on your activity, which will call onCreateOptionsMenu and set the new title.

Comment: This just seems to add another button into the action bar instead of changing the title

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YOUR TITLE HERE");
```

Inside **on create**, *after initializing ui or viewbinding or databinding.*

Comment: This works perfect for me, easy and functional solution. thanks u

Answer (score 1):

I am changing the title of the menu from `onPrepareOptionMenu` something like the below code. This is the code from my fragment, I think this should also work on the activity.

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    if (count == 1) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.screen_count).title = "1/3"
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.screen_count).title = "xyz/3"
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.ic_edit -> {
            // handle click event here
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```