# Is there a way to change the menu title at run-time?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there anyway to change the strings at runtime in java.
please check my updated question
in mainActivity.java i want to change menu item title

can i set menu item title in MainActivity.java because i want to change title in some conditions how to settitle in java file...

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">check</string>
    <string name="title_home">Home</string>
    <string name="title_dashboard">Dashboard</string>
    <string name="title_notifications">Notifications</string>
</resources>
```

The navigation menu where I have used the strings

**menu_nevigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dash"
        android:title="@string/title_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dash"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Initialize And Assign Variable
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

             menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent
    MenuItem menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.home);  //menu is the menuhere
    menuitem.setTitle("Your title");

        //Set Home Selected
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);


        //Perform ItemSelected
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.dash:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,dash.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                    case R.id.home:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.notifications:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                                ,notifications.class));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Could you try reformulating your question? It isn't quite clear

Comment: title_home, title_dashboard, title_notifications these 3 strings i am using in menu title i want to set title in mainactivity.java @AdityaKurkure please check updated question..

Comment: So basically you want to edit your string resource in run time right?

Comment: yes i want to edit menu title in mainactivity.java @AdityaKurkure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation in the comments I am guessing that you want to change your R.string folder at run-time. Which is not possible. In fact the entire res folder cannot be modified at run-time.

If you want to change the menu titles at runtime

```
menu = mynavigationview.getMenu()  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent
MenuItem menuitem = menu.getItem(*insert item index here*);  //menu is the menu here 
menuitem.setTitle("Your title");
```

This should work. If you want to keep the titles stored then you should use shared preferences to do so and set them from the preferences each time your application is launched.

Comment: menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu()  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent
        MenuItem home = menu.findItem(R.id.home);  //menu is the menuhere
        home.setTitle("Your title");    NOT WORKING @AdityaKurkure

Comment: please check i updated mainactivity.java in question @AdityaKurkure..

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable menu @AdityaKurkure

Comment: Menu menu = mynavigationview.getMenu()  //mynavigationview is the name of your navigationcomponent
MenuItem menuitem = menu.findtem(*insert item index here*);  //menu is the menu here 
menuitem.setTitle("Your title"); please update answer. @AdityaKurkure

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your navigationView with findViewById(R.id.nav_view_id), then:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menuItem_id);
// or MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0) if you have one MenuItem
```

Then you create a method in which you will choose which title you currently need.

```
//for example
 protected String getMyTitle(){
    if(/*something*/){
        return getResources().getString(R.id.title_home);
    }else if(/*something*/){
        return getResources().getString(R.id.title_dashboard);
    }else{
        return getResources().getString(R.id.title_notifications);
    }
}
```

And as a result, we put the text in item.

```
item.setTitle(getMyTitle());
```

This link may also help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617132/how-to-set-the-title-of-a-menu-in-android)

Comment: title_home, title_dashboard, title_notifications these 3 strings i am using in menu title i want to set title in mainactivity.java @Razrab.ytka please check updated question..

Comment: your answer is now helping but i got it already thank you so much for help me @Razrab.ytka